# FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'published_date' into field

Tags: django, django-models

i am creating a new blog django apllication but when run it i got error
here is my code

```
#model.py
class Post(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey('auth.user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text=models.TextField()
    create_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    pubished_date=models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    def publish(self):
        self.published_date=timezone.now()
        self.save()
    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comments=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):

    post=models.ForeignKey('blog.Post',related_name='comments')
    author=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    test=models.TextField()
    create_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    approved_comment=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment=True
        self.save()
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_list')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

whenerver i run server i got this field error message. i m new to django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Post` model you have a typo in `pubished_date`, it's may be `published_date`

Comment: here, also typo `self.published_date=timezone.now()` and also run migrations after renaming filed name